# How to expand Linux partition

Tags: partitioning

Hey guys I've been using Linux Ubuntu for a while and wanted to add some more space, I created a new partition on the disk and booted from the usb and used gpartes software but there's no option to expand the partition where Linux is installed, does anyone know what I need to do?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Not really, I've been trying that for a while

Comment: We don't see what is the problem. Most likely there is no space to expand the partition adjacent. Move other partitions to get the space.

Comment: If you could show us a screenshot of `gparted` that you see maybe we can help you more.

Comment: I'm trying to solve a problem, I'll send the print in a second

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/bvL0rf2

Comment: Here's a print with the partitions, Linux is installed on the 32gb

Comment: if you have live Ubuntu usb disk, then boot it from live Ubuntu usb disk and when Ubuntu is successfully loaded/booted then launch gparted and you can perform expand.

You can't edit the live partition that's the reason you are unable to edit/expand the partition

Comment: Your image is of the disks app, not GParted. You appear to have just 538 MB that is free. That’s about 0.5GB, so not very much. If you run GParted from a Ubuntu live usb or CD you should be able to make your 32GB partition slightly larger. However I wonder if there is a second disk that you created a new partition on. The other 3 partitions on this disk look like regular Windows partitions

Comment: **WARNING** Never mind the disk partitioning... your image shows that the temps are WAY outside of normal. Are your fans working, or working overtime?

Comment: I agree with @heynnema here.  That is way too hot for a drive to be operating at.  Is this a NVME drive?  If so, I would definitely recommend a heatsink / fan for a NVME as they are known to get really hot!  Why the drive maker doesn't include a heatsink / fan for those is beyond me.